# React does not render (in the first go) with respect to an array defines within the function or even passed as props

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I am using a functional component with the name ChatListComponent. I tried defining the userCommunities array within the function but still the inner loop didn't log anything unless I did something that would rerender the components once again.

Later I tried passing that same array from the parent component, her also the inner loop only works when the components are forced to rerender.

If anyone knows how to solve it, please help me out.

```
export default function ChatListComponent(props) {
  console.log(props.userCommunities);
  return (
    <div className="chat--list red">
      {props.userCommunities.forEach((element) => {
        console.log(element);
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: what is the output of 1st log?

Comment: If you use .map and actually return a JSX element does the behavior change?

Comment: what do you mean by "forced to rerender"? either it renders with data or it renders without it, so it should always log something, even if its undefined

Comment: `forEach` does not return anything and does not make sense to include directly in your JSX.

Answer (score 0):

Your example is working nice on codesandbox ([link](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-playground-forked-b36kn?file=/index.js)).

Make sure your list is not empty, and your component is rendered.

Answer (score 0):

Kindly use map method of Array because forEach can only iterate and return nothing.
Below is sample snippet which render element which we pass in props

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

export default function ChatListComponent(props) {
  console.log(props.userCommunities);
  return (
    <div className="chat--list red">
      {props.userCommunities.map((element) => {
        console.log(element);
        return <p>{element}</p>
      })}
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <ChatListComponent userCommunities={['a','b','d']} />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

please find codesandbox link https://codesandbox.io/s/simple-render-props-data-sqw4z for demo